# How to load data to specific input value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I am having this piece of code, to load data form PHP after users click on link.
Then I am displaying received data to div id="vies":

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#data-received").hide();
      $("#click_me").click(function(){
        $("#data-received").show();
        $("#vies").load('127.0.0.1/get_data/', {VATID : $("#vat_id").val()});   
      });
    });
</script>


<label>VATID</label>
<input type="text" id="vat_id" name="vat_id" value="">
<a href="#" id="click_me">Check VATID</a>


<div id="data-received">
    <label>Data received from PHP</label>
    <div id="vies">.. checking ..
        <input type="text" name="put-here" id="put-here" value="test-value"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The question is how to load data and insert **as a input value** here:

```
<input type="text" name="put-here" id="put-here" value="test-value"/>
```

instead to whole div.

Comment: Can you give us an exmple of the data you get from /get_data/?

Comment: Mor Haviv:
In this simple example I need to pass just one variable.

But in reality I need to receive whole data from PHP (name, address, postcode etc.) and then paste the data as a few inputs. Is there any way to receive a array from PHP or this need to be done in different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#data-received").hide();
        $("#click_me").click(function(){
            $("#data-received").show();
            $.post('http://127.0.0.1/get_data/', {
                VATID : $("#vat_id").val()
            }, function(data) {
                $('#put-here').val(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a convenience function which does an ajax request and then replaces the target element with the data returned. When you don't want to replace the whole element, use [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do the request. In the success callback you can set your value to the returned data using [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

```
$.ajax({
  url: "127.0.0.1/get_data/",
  data: {VATID : $("#vat_id").val()}
}).done(function(data) {
  $( '#put-here' ).val(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the provided information. I wronlgy thought that I can use load() function.